# jQuery status indication by file on web server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web server. On the web server there is a process running that is doing something. While the process (or program) is running it will post updates on the status of the task it is doing that should indicate more or less when it will be finished. (Like a status bar indicator for example with percentage number)

The process (or program) will write to a file called busy.html - Inside busy.html the following will be written by the process: **Processing: 50%**

busy.html is located at: http://www.somewhere.com/temp/busy.html for example.

The process on the web server will intermittently write to busy.html while it is working until 100% is reached. When 100% is reached busy.html will be removed.

On a web page I would like to have jQuery code that displays the contents of  busy.html to indicate the status or progress of the process the web server is busy with.

So in other words, Jquery should poll and display the contents of busy.html inside an existing web page until busy.html does not exist anymore.

How would the Jquery code for this look like? Perhaps there is a much easier way of passing on the progress status to jQuery instead of using a file to indicate the existing status like explained here.

**Update to my question:**

Also, would this be the proper way (using jQuery) to indicate the status of a process running on the server? I would like to enter a URL that is password protected and the web page that loads should tell me the status of the process running on the server. The tech that is running the process is a Perl script or program that is busy indexing the contents of files into a database.

Comment: Can't you just take the code from busy.html and use it on a page?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ also be wary of reading a file from the local disk. It can easily get locked if multiple connections attempt to access it.

Comment: So does the page have markup that you can look for to get the status? How do you want to display it on your page?

Comment: What tech are you using on the server?  If it's C# then use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
var place = $('#foo');
var delay = 3 * 1000; // 3 seconds
var url = 'http://www.somewhere.com/temp/busy.html';
(function recur() {
   $.ajax({url: url, success: function(page) {
      place.html(page);
      setTimeout(function() {
          recur();
      }, delay);
   }, error: function() {
     place.hide();
   }});
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need.

- Read JQuery [post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) or [get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) method and see [simple example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp).
- Inside document ready call a post or get request (get would do with your scenario) and url will point to busy.html
- In response you will get data that is your html or text written inside busy.html
- You can then use the last three letters of that text to fetch percentage and show a chart, guage or simple text as you wish.

Its not complicated.